# Why does the method get_pinned_message() break when used according to the documentation?

Tags: python, telethon

I want to get every pinned `message` from chat(with id == main_id):

```
@client.on(events.ChatAction(chats=main_id))
async def normal_handler(event):
    if event.new_pin:
        pin = await event.get_pinned_message()
```

But this method always returns an error:[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like a bug, please report it in the library's GitHub page and I may investigate it, providing reproduction steps and situation.